# Unable to integrate a customGPT ( https://chat.openai.com/g/g-slaywGsMo-recruitgpt ) to my website as a chat feature?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

Disclaimer: I am a rookie so pardon if the question is too basic

I used the below PHP code on my website (ChatGPT generated)

```
<?php
// Giving demo value to $_POST['data'] for testing
$_POST['data']="I am an Android Developer. Can you help me find a relevant Job?";
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $userData = $_POST['data'];

    // RecruitGPT API endpoint and your API key
    $apiUrl = 'YOUR_RECRUITGPT_API_ENDPOINT';
    $apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

    // Setting up the request to the API
    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['input' => $userData]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        // Other necessary headers
    ]);

    // Execute the request and get the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        // Process the response
        $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

        // Assuming the API returns a 'response' field in its JSON
        echo $decodedResponse['response'];
    }

    // Close the cURL session
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    echo "No data provided";
}
?>
```

I generated the API key from https://platform.openai.com/api-keys
I am not sure of the YOUR_RECRUITGPT_API_ENDPOINT

Can someone help?

I have tried the below combination for 'YOUR_RECRUITGPT_API_ENDPOINT'

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/g/g-slaywGsMo-recruitgpt/completions
https://chat.openai.com/g/g-slaywGsMo-recruitgpt
```